# How can I write this more "ruby-ish"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got the following snippet

```
Class Artist < ActiveRecord
   attr_accessible :solo #boolean

  def change_solo!
    if self.solo == false
     self.solo = true
    else
     self.solo = false
    end
   self.save
  end

end
```

Is there a better way to write that? Thanks in advance
cheers tabaluga

Comment: `self.solo = self.solo == true ? false : true` (closer to your first) or `self.solo = not self.solo` (more ruby-ish, perhaps) and are at least more concise

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha!  I can shrink it even further, heh:

```
def change_solo!
  update_attribute :solo, !solo
end
```

This does the save automatically.

But it wouldn't be complete without tests:

```
def test_change_solo_true_to_false
  Artist.create :solo => true
  assert Artist.change_solo!
  assert !Artist.solo?
end

def test_change_solo_false_to_true
  Artist.create :solo => false
  assert Artist.change_solo!
  assert Artist.solo?
end
```

By the way, above I use the convention that any boolean attribute in ActiveRecord can have a question mark at the end to make it more self-explanatory.

Comment: Perfect! Thumbsup and a big Thankyou

Comment: You should also assert that the record was saved (that the method returned true).

Answer (score 28):

Don't write this method. Use [ActiveRecord::Base#toggle!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle%21) instead:

```
artist_object.toggle!(:solo)
```

This method also exists in Rails 2, if you haven't upgraded yet.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this :

```
Class Artist < ActiveRecord 
attr_accessible :solo #boolean 
  def change_solo! 
   self.solo = !self.solo
   self.save 
  end 
end
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, ActiveRecord::Base#update_attribute does not run validations, so you rarely want to use this method.